# Loop in simple arduino code is not working

Tags: arduino

I am working on simple project, arduino relay controled via mobile phone. I am trying to create a loop, which makes the relay switch between `HIGH` and `LOW` only with sending 1 to pin 7. I tried multiple variations but it never works, I am unable to find a mistake. Here´s the code, thanks in advance.`

```
int relay = 7;
int prev; //previous value
int val; //actual value

void setup()
{
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
if(Serial.available()>0) //send data when recieved 
  {
   val = Serial.read(); //read value
  }

  if (val == '1')
  {
    if (prev == '1')
    {
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
     prev=val;  
    }
    else
    {
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
     prev=val; 
    }  
   }
  else if (val == '0');
  {
    if (prev == '0')
    {
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
     prev=val; 
    }
    else 
    {
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);  
     prev=val; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current code attempts to read the serial port, and if has something to read sets it into variable val.

In the case of where it has read a value, but doesnt have another value, val is still set to the same value as before.

So it then probally starts toggling the high/low transition as fast as the loop can go.

Instead, you could move the logic code to within the if(Serial.available()>0) statement so that it only gets called when the key is pressed.